# Method marked as abstract but not shown by javap

Tags: java, jvm, javac, bytecode

Its a very peculiar case, seems to be a .class file corruption. Our Application depends on a dependency provided by other team. There are 2 java files of relevance: `FTGService` and `FTGServiceLight implements FTGService`.

So when I do `javap -p FTGService` it prints:

```
....  
public abstract java.util.List<munshi.transfers.domain.TransferredFile> getArchivedFilesByLastSyncTime(java.util.Date, java.util.Date, java.util.Date, java.util.Date, java.util.Date, java.util.List<java.lang.String>, java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>);
```

On doing `javap -p FTGServiceLight`, it prints:

```
....  
public java.util.List<munshi.transfers.domain.TransferredFile> getArchivedFilesByLastSyncTime(java.util.Date, java.util.Date, java.util.Date, java.util.Date, java.util.Date, java.util.List<java.lang.String>, java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>);
....
```

When I do `javap -v FTGServiceLight`, the relevant information can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/3LtLZ7mE).

But on running it throws an error:

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   munshi.transfers.service.light.FTGServiceLight.getArchivedFilesByLastSyncTime(Ljava/util/Date;Ljava/util/Date;Ljava/util/Date;Ljava/util/Date;Ljava/util/Date;Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/util/List;
>     at
>   broker.services.resolver.impl.FileSyncServiceImpl.fetchFiles(FileSyncServiceImpl.java:71)
>     at
>   broker.services.resolver.impl.TransferFileSync.run(TransferFileSync.java:71)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor129.invoke(Unknown Source)    at

`getArchivedFilesByLastSyncTime` is being marked as `abstract` for some reason. Further when I debug it, this is what it shows as on doing:

```
FTGServiceLight.getMethod("getArchivedFilesByLastSyncTime",Date.class,Date.class,Date.class,Date.class,Date.class, List.class, List.class))
```

[image]

Note `modifiers` is shown as `1025` and doing `Modifiers.isAbstract(1025)` returns `true`. So the method `getArchivedFilesByLastSyncTime` on debugging is shown as `abstract` but `javap` suggests it other wise. But when I decompile `FTGServiceLight`, it indeed shows the method [body](http://picpaste.com/sp2-kXyhDuxs.png), so it seems like it is overridden.

What might be causing this behavior

PS: I have checked mvn dependency tree, and an alternative version for this class never comes in picture.

Comment: Perhaps you have multiple versions of the class lying around, and the one Javap sees is different from the one the JVM is looking at.

Comment: As mentioned in post script. There is only one dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a multiple dependencies issue indeed. Just inspecting Maven dependency tree doesn't ensure that you don't have multiple versions of the same class at runtime.

It can be cached, it can be loaded from a different place, etc. In the FileSyncServiceImpl, try printing out the location from where the FTGServiceLight was loaded:

```
 System.out.println(
    FTGServiceLight.class.getClassLoader().getResource(
        FTGServiceLight.class.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class"));
```

And compare to the context where this class is used:

```
 System.out.println(
    FileSyncServiceImpl.class.getClassLoader().getResource(
        FileSyncServiceImpl.class.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class"));
```

Is it the same classlaoder?

One more thing you can try is to inspect what are the locations that the classloader is using to load the classes from. In FileSyncServiceImpl do:

```
 System.out.print(
    Arrays.toString(((URLClassLoader)
        Test1.class.getClassLoader()).getURLs()));
```

It will give you the list of jar files (and directories) that are located by this classloader. You can then check if FTGServiceLight is located in any of those and if it is present multiple times.

Comment: Thanks @Anton. Your first suggestion helped me solve the problem. The Issue was: A lot of our jars are auto-generated. It so happened, that there was some jar in my dependency which also contained `FTGServiceLight` in the same package structure. But the file belonged to previous version, and while auto-generation it included the previous version file.

And my application picked up that one, resulting in error.